# javascript httpget

Tags: javascript, http-get

I am trying this script from html, but can tget a result, what is a problem?

```
<script>
function httpGet()
    {
var httpClient = util.newHttpClient();
var result = httpClient.get("www.google.com");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result;
    return results;
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="httpGet()">Display site</button>
```

Comment: you should learn javascript first....

Comment: `util.newHttpClient` does not exist and cannot be synchronous.

Comment: also use http:// in front of url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot use AJAX to read content from a different website.

Comment: You can't.  You may want to use JSONP or a server-side proxy.